# Updating gitlab project ci/cd variables

Tags: gitlab-ci

->I have declared a variable in the CI/CD variable section of my gitlab project, attached is the snapshot:

[image]

->In my project.yml, I can read the value using "$master_major_version_no"

->But if I want to update the value like $master_major_version_no = "xyz", it's not
retaining the value after the job is finished.

->Any help on how to retain the updated value of the variable after the job finishes.

**Tried the curl update command, but getting **422** error

[image]

Comment: That is opinionated but I don't think CI variables are meant to be updated. Definitely not using any syntax from a job. Maybe using Gitlab API but I would strongly recommend to think twice about it. Version of a software is usually derived from git tags or a file from the package manager you're using.

Answer (score 0):

GitLab does not allow dynamic changing of CI variables in a running job. You can however modify variables before a pipeline is started however using any of the following methods:

- [Run a pipeline manually](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/index.html#run-a-pipeline-manually) in the UI.
- Create a pipeline by using the API (either [the pipelines API endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#create-a-new-pipeline) or [the triggers API endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/index.html#pass-cicd-variables-in-the-api-call))
- Use [push options.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html#push-options-for-gitlab-cicd)

This is explained in more detail in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#override-a-defined-cicd-variable).